# Android streaming sound

Tags: android, stream, streaming

I am doing a streamed musicplayer for android.
I have tried with MediaPlayer

```
mp.setDataSource("http://www.myServerPage.com/songUrl.mp3"); 
mp.prepare(); 
mp.start();
```

and it works but not good.
The  prepare state is very slow and often the application is freezing.

I have searched a lot on forums and tutorials and as far as I can see this is the common way of doing it.

Do anyone know is it is another way of opening up a stream to play music from a server or have any good advices, maybe in NDK or by some other inputstream?

Thanks for the help.
/micke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Media Playback article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) is pretty clear about how to deal with remote media sources: call `prepareAsync()` and set a listener to get notified when the source is ready for playing.

The reason for this is exactly what you're experiencing:

> (...) the call to prepare() can take a long time to execute, because it
>   might involve fetching and decoding media data. So, as is the case
>   with any method that may take long to execute, you should **never call
>   it from your application's UI thread**. Doing that will cause the UI
>   to hang until the method returns, which is a very bad user experience
>   and can cause an ANR (Application Not Responding) error.

I suggest you go over the mentioned article for some more information and pointers that may help you with further development.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So even the commerical applicatios Spotify etc, use this way of playing streamed music.

Comment: @bajenmicke: I can't speak for Spotify, but I'm closely familiar with another music app (that is distributed by a couple device manufacturers as part of their ROM) and yes, that one uses the standard `MediaPlayer` and `prepareAsync()` for playing *all* content, be it local or remote. Depending on your app's specifics, you may also want to consider setting up a dedicated `Service` to host the `MediaPlayer`.